# Jquery: Retrieve array from cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

im having some difficulty trying to pull out a specific value from a cookie.
im using the cookie plugin found here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

```
var cookieString = "{'zip':'" + $( '#ZipCode' ).val() + "','age':'" + $( '#age' ).val() + "','gender':'" + $( '#gender' ).val() +"}";
$.cookie("rememberMe", ( ($( '#rememberMe' ).attr( 'checked' ))?cookieString:null ), { path: '/', expires: 60 });
alert($.cookie("rememberMe"));
```

which will return correctly:

```
{'zip':'91210','age':'99','gender':'male'}
```

now im just having trouble with pulling out specifically one of the items in the array.
for example how would i just pull out the value of 'zip'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to invoke the Javascript compiler and convert the string into an object:

```
var obj = eval('(' + $.cookie("rememberMe") + ')');
alert(obj['zip']);
```